# Show that $f(z) = \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{1-z} \right)$ is analytical

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

I would like to show that the function $f(z) = \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{1-z} \right)$ is analytical on $]-1,1[$.

I could use the fact the composition of 2 analytical functions is an analytical function.

I know that we say that $f$ is analytical on $U = ]-1, +1[$ if $f$ is expandable in power series $\forall z_0 \in  U$.

And $f$ is expandable in power series at point $z_0 \in U$ if there is,

- $r > 0$ such that $D(z_0, r) \subset U$
- a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$ where its radius of convergence $\rho$ is greater or equal to $r$ and such that

$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n, \quad \forall z_0 \in D(z_0, r)
$$

I can feel that the function $f(z) = \sin(z)$ is analytical because it is expandable in the power series,
$$
\sin(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}
$$
whose radius of convergence $\rho = +\infty$ so it is expandable in power series on $]-1,1[$.

The same idea for $f(z) = \frac{\pi}{1-z}$, it is analytical because we can use the geometric series,
$$
 \frac{\pi}{1-z} = \pi \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} z^n, \quad |z| < 1
$$
so it is expandable in power series on $]-1,1[$.

So you can see I feel the idea but I struggle to use the proposition to justify rigorously that these two functions are analytical. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: There is a little error in you proof (and in @Gary's comment): you do not have to show that $\sin$ is analytic on $]-1,1[$ or on the unit disk, but on the image of the function $z \mapsto \frac{\pi}{1-z}$, and use this fact: if $f : A \to B$ and $g : B\to C$ are analityic, then $g \circ f ; A \to C$ is analytic.

Comment: @Didier Oh, yes. That was a huge mistake of mine.